# delete operation in generic linked list

Tags: c, generics, memory-management, linked-list

How do I know if the value pointed to by the address stored in the data variable is in the stack or the heap? if it is stored in the heap I will call the free() function.

```
struct node{
   void *data;
   struct node *prev, *next;
};
void delete(struct node *head, void *data){
    //search process
    free(iter->data);
}
```

Comment: You can have a variable that stores where the object was created from (i.e., it's storage type):  heap (dynamic, or in the global store), stack (automatic), static, thread_local.  You could pass a "deleter" functor, that takes the address as a parameter and "does the right thing" based on how/where the object was created.

Comment: If the list doesn't do its own memory handling of the data, then you can't. It's up to the *user* of the list to handle it instead.

Comment: Why would you want to allow storing data from stack in a linked list? Besides the issue with freeing of not freeing the memory you may run into lifetime issues if you add an element from within a function and then return from that function. Mixing stack and hep data is begging for trouble

Comment: @Eljay thanks I guess it can be handled using enum

Comment: Storing pointers to heap memory and pointers to non heap memory in the same list looks like a design error to me in the first place. Your problem looks like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me